# Jenkinsfile : how to modify a string parameter passed in pipeline jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins pipeline.

Under my **jenkinsfile** , i'm calling an ansible playbook within a shell command :

It looks like this :

```
stage('Run Playbook') {
  steps {
    script{
      sh " ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml \
          -e myparam=\"${MY_PARAM}\" "
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see : in the job my param is **MY_PARAM** , it's a string parameter , and it may contain some spaces.

My purpose is to replace all spaces woth comma (-)  , and pass it to the playbook ?

so i was suggested to inject :

```
.replace('', '-')
```

but with jenkinsfile syntax , i wasn t able to do it correctly

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything inside the `${...}` is a regular Groovy expression, so you can do whatever sorts of translations you'd like.

```
stage('Run Playbook') {
  steps {
    script {
      sh "ansible -playbook myplaybook.yml -e myparam=\"${MY_PARAM.replace(' ', '-')}\""
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can do this replacement in an `environment` block.

```
stage('Run Playbook') {
  environment {
    ANSIBLE_MY_PARAM="${MY_PARAM.replace(' ', '-')}"
  }
  steps {
    script {
      sh "ansible -playbook myplaybook.yml -e myparam=\"${ANSIBLE_MY_PARAM}\""
    }
  }
}
```

but that seems overkill in this limited case.

Comment: for some reason when i was doing it. if you wanted to use as a variable doesn't work, you need to put it into a string such:     new_var="{$ANSIBLE_MY_PARM}".replace(" ", "-")